# How to add PHP extension to PHP project in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I've installed eclipse 4.8, PDT.
I've created new php project.

Why Eclipse cant find ZipArchive class?

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive(); // ERROR: ZipArchive cannot be resolved to a type
$zip->
```

I have Linux Ubuntu with PHP7.0 and zip extension installed.
What I have to do to have code completion for classes and methods in php zip extension?

// EDIT

1. I have installed extensions in my PHP cli:

> ```
> php -a
> Interactive mode enabled
> php > $zip = new ZipArchive();
> php > $zip
> php > echo get_class($zip);
> php > var_dump(get_class($zip));
> string(10) "ZipArchive"
> php >
> ```

Comment: Double check that you've enabled the zip-extension for CLI as well. IDE's usually uses the CLI version for linting and such.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Yes. In fact I dont have completion for any php extensions: DOM (DOMDocument), mbstring, ... . I even dont have completion for functions like array_xxx()

Comment: Something is wrong with your buildpath, please edit .buildpath file and add "<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>" see also https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502184 for more information

Comment: BTW: how you prepared your project? Via "new project" or project -> configure? I'm looking for way to finally fix mentioned bug.

Comment: Same problem here with a fresh Eclipse installation and Cassandra PECL extension which is accessible through PHP CLI but I get a lot of `cannot be resolved to a type` errors. `.buildpath` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your .buildpath is broken edit and add this `<buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>`

For example can looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```